# Textbook integration problem. Unclear how the limit was arrived at.

Tags: calculus

I am looking at this text:

[image]

and I'm not clear how (b) was arrived at. (a) makes sense to me. How did they go from:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n e^{1 + 2i/n}$$

to the long fraction on the right? What is even going on?

Comment: By using a computer to solve it for them, apparently.

Comment: **"Now we ask the computer algebra system to evaluate the limit"**

Comment: The sum is obtained by summing the geometric series, and that's all.  No computer is required here.

Comment: [Don't use \frac in exponents or limits of integrals](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189)

Answer (score 3):

If you *wanted* to get that expression by hand, you could note that the sum is geometric and use (with some modifications) the general rule

$$\sum_{i=0}^m ar^i = a\frac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}\qquad\textrm{when $|r| < 1$.}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\frac {2}{n}\sum_\limits{i=1}^n e^{1+\frac {2i}{n}} = $$\frac {2}{n}(e^{1+\frac {2}{n}} + e^{1+\frac {4}{n}} + e^{1+\frac {6}{n}} +\cdots + e^{3})\\
\frac {2}{n}(e)(e^{\frac 2n} + e^{\frac {4}{n}} + e^{\frac {6}{n}} +\cdots + e^{2})$

And the factor on the right is a geometric series.

i.e. $\sum_\limits{i=1}^{n} r^{i} = \frac {r(1-r^n)}{1-r}$ and let $r = e^\frac{2}{n}$

$\frac {2}{n}(e)\frac {e^{\frac 2n}(1 - e^{2})}{1-e^\frac {2}{n}} = \frac {2}{n}\frac {e^{\frac {3n+ 2}{n}} - e^{\frac {n + 2}{n}}}{e^\frac {2}{n} - 1}$